# TestCafe expect() scope

Tags: testing, meteor, automated-tests, testcafe, end-to-end

I'm new to TestCafe and I am struggling to achieve a test in a "clean way" using roles.
I've been reading the docs from TestCafe and got insipired by this "tutorial" https://github.com/qualityshepherd/testcafe-example for creating my tests.

I have to write a test that tests if a user is correctly logged in. For that I want to use Roles. This is the architecture of my test scripts and I will explain why I do this choices:

- data

  - roles.js **this is where I defined the Roles**
- pages (folder)

  - base-page.js **the wrapper of all pages (where I have content like toolbar/navbar/...**
  - login-page.js **my login page**
  - status-page.js **the page after a successful login**
- tests

  - login.test.js **the test that doesn't work like I want to**

Let's dive into some pieces of code. 
This is my *login.test.js* file:

```js
import basePage from '../../pages/base-page';

fixture `Account management`;

test('Login with valid account',
    async (t) => {
        await t
            .useRole(validUser) // this logs me in using a Role defined in another file
            .expect(basePage.userSection.exists).ok() // check if exists
            .expect(basePage.userSection.child(1).textContent).eql('somevalid.username'); // check if value is the one I expect
    }
);

// other tests...
```

The *roles.js* file:

```js
import { Role } from 'testcafe';
import loginPage from '../pages/login-page.js';

// I will obviously not display any valid data on this post
export const validUser = Role(
    loginPageUrl,
    async (t) => {
        await loginPage.login(t, someValidEmail, someValidPassword);
    },
    { preserveUrl: true }
);
```

My *base-page.js* file:

```js
// imports 

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const basePage = {
    baseUrl,
    userSection: $('div.navigation-account-dropdown.js-user-menu'), // some section on my navbar
    [... other stuff you don't need to know about]
}

export default basePage;
```

My *login-page.js* file:

```js
import { Selector as $, t } from 'testcafe';
import basePage from './base-page';

// FIXME: I do not want to use .expect(...) here but in the proper test file (login.test.js)
const loginPage = {
    url: `${basePage.baseUrl}signin`,
    usernameInput: $('#at-field-email'),
    passwordInput: $('#at-field-password'),
    loginBtn: $('#at-pwd-form').find('button'),

    async login(t, username, password) {
        await t
            .typeText(this.usernameInput, username)
            .typeText(this.passwordInput, password)
            .click(this.loginBtn) // I want to stop the logic here and do the assertion on the proper test.js file
            .expect(basePage.userSection.exists).ok(); // I do not want to do assertions here but I have to do it otherwise tests fails
    }
}

export default {
    ...basePage,
    ...loginPage
};
```

The problem is that when I comment the line `.expect(basePage.userSection.exists).ok();` in the *login-page.js* file the test doesn't run as expected. It fills the form, clicks submit and then nothing happens (I am still in login page, it is reloaded). So I added one assertion here to make it "work". But I don't want any assertion here, it shouldn't be here but in the actual test file.
My main question is: how can I remove any assertion from my login-page.js file. Why do I have to do that .expect there in order for the test to pass?

Do you have any tips/advices regarding how to structure a project test (I have to write a lot of tests so that's why I am trying to separate some logics)?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you described is unexpected. As a possible solution, use the `preserveUrl` option: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#optionspreserveurl.

If it does not help, we need to research the problem in detail. Please share your example and create a separate issue in the TestCafe github repository using the following form: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md.

If you cannot share your project here, you can send it to support@devexpress.com.

Please note that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to further research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us (support@devexpress.com) written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: I do use preserveUrl, it doesn't work othersiwe. I've also tried disablePageCaching like suggested in the documentation.  Sorry but we can't provide our project (startup policy), I've shared evertything about the login testing here in my question. Anyways, thanks for your anwser, I will continue to do my testing with this hack. It doesn't impact my other tests (this is one over almost a hundred). But still I will be interested of understanding why it has to be like this.

Comment: It is understandable you can't provide the full project, but you can report an issue using the form [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide a small project reproducing the problem